# How can I do custom event for component in react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to add a new custom event for the checkbox. I want to add an event not other than known events. How can I make this? Is it possible to do this? Can you help me, please? Thanks.

Comment: explain problem with sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom events using `CustomEvent`

```js
// add an appropriate event listener
something.addEventListener("eureka", function(e) { process(e.detail) });

// create and dispatch the event
var event = new CustomEvent("eureka", {
  detail: {
    floatingBot: true
  }
});
obj.dispatchEvent(event);
```

More on this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent